# CRUD, How to keep the page at current create page url after submit

Tags: php, laravel-4, crud

I have a create account page when i submit from **account/create** page it redirect to **account/**. 
In Laravel (CRUD), 
how can I keep the current url at current create page after submitting form. I don't want it to redirect to **account/**
 Let say the account validation is fail so i want it stay on current create page.

*This is my route:*

```
Route::resource('account', 'AccountsController');
```

*this is my blade:*

```
{{ Form::open(array('route'=>'account.store')) }}
```

*My create function:*

```
public function create()
    {
        //

        return View::make('accounts.create');
    }
```

Comment: What does the create funtion look like in the AccountsController?

Comment: Oops, i meant the store function, but @peterm has given you the solution anyway.

Comment: He give the answer that I want. Anyway thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `store()` method of `AccountController` when the validation fails you can just do

```php
return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
```

Comment: Great! Thank you peterm! That is what I want. Just want to add a little bit. How could I write when i want to pass **->with('messages', $result_message);**?

Comment: Ok i get it now I just add **return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator)->with('messages', $result_message);** and get as session. I love stackoverflow. I love you and everyone here ^^